# Multiple monitors on dedicated and onboard gpu

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, display

I am trying to connect 2 monitors, one on external gpu and one on motherboard, however monitor connected on motherboard is not recognized. I turned on integrated gpu and surround view in bios and i can see it in device manager. I am using Radeon HD 7850 as my main graphic card and integrated is radeon 3000. But monitor is still black. Also i tried everything in Primary video controller option in bios, but everytime same results.
You can see screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: video drivers recognize that a monitor is connected by the 75 Ohm termination on the signal which is reported to windows. Display resolution should show device if connected.  But try shorter cable in case of poor signal integrity if HDMI, otherwise if VGA no need.  Long HDMI cables can cause poor signals in cheap cables.

Comment: Monitor connected to dedicated gpu is connected via adapter vga/dvi, on integrated graphic it is just vga.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the Windows Display Property, which should detect all displays, make sure you enable all the highlighted monitors by selecting 'Extend my Windows Desktop Onto This Monitor option' for all the highlighted monitors.

Comment: Windows won't recognize  http://i.imgur.com/SacHrQL.png

Comment: is it VGA,  DVI or HDMI?  what about disable PCI in bios? check cable and pins

Comment: Cables are working fine, main monitor is conected to the adapter VGA female/DVI male. Second monitor is connected to the internal graphic via  VGA cable(no adapters). Also i tried to connect the other monitor to a dedicated graphic card via adapter HDMI to VGA and pc still won't recognize it.

Comment: does monitor work in anything?

Comment: Yes they both work

Comment: Only time I have seen this required a System Restore.  Are any onboard Intel or similiar services disabled

Comment: The computer is fully amd

Comment: You really shouldn't be using vga for anything these days. It's not really supported. I can't say it's causing your problem... But it could be related.

Comment: @CliffArmstrong  I was referring the "physical VGA port" not the VGA resolution.  I still use VGA with 1920x1680 with flawless quality on an 8 Core Win7 machine..

Comment: I was also talking about physical VGA ports. And no, you don't. VGA doesn't offer "flawless quality" at *any* resolution because it's not digital. Specifically, it produces a blurry image... especially at higher resolutions. It also doesn't allow for any form of EDID for identification of the monitor... which could be a major factor in the problem here. VGA hasn't been viable for desktop use in over a decade. And 1920x1680? The vast majority of flat panel monitors are 16:9... not 4:3. You need to use the resolution that matches your monitor if you want good quality (never mind "flawless").

Comment: With only 8 bit resolution or 256:1 you get 43dB SNR and with analog DAC signals this is easy to achieve to be flawless, then DAC frequency response determines contrast ratio for alternating pixels black white and Monitor PLL can lock onto the correct frequency and phase of the pixel voltage.  THat's my experience. Sorry about brain fart.  1920x1080. I use a Hitachi  54" monitor at 1m distance. I have also long ago used 4K resolutions on CRT's with high SNR using the VGA port on monitors with > 250MHz BW.  FWIW @CliffArmstrong  your mileage may vary.

Comment: I used VGA because my ASUS 8x i8 tower seems to have poor HDMI quality with  noisy pixels on high contrast zones due to CM noise on my HDMI port. With my finger on the HDMI transmission line SMD CM Choke on the MOBO , I discovered my finger capacitance affects the HDMI noise.  Laptop, no noise, but Tower with 3 different HDMI cables varied in noise from poor, good to flawless until it was bent slightly. then not reversible due to auto-equalization of the GHz signals and COmmon mode noise on the MOBO.  So I stayed with VGA